# jQuery Form Crashes when Radio Button is Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have this form that uses jQuery. It works great except for one thing: When a user clicks the radio button called "Isuzu NPR-HD-Gas," the page's layout disappears! This happens in every browser. All of the other options in the form work great, it's just this one radio button that causes the problem. What can be causing this problem?

Here's the link: http://www.unitedtruckcenters.com/custompage.asp?pg=compare-to-isuzu

Note: Please scroll down and click on "Isuzu NPR-HD-Gas" to see what I am talking about.

Comment: You have to paste you code to the question because external links can be found broken in future

Comment: and no one wants to click on a random link in case of viruses

Comment: It's not crashing, You'll find it's because of `$('td:nth-child(' + hide + '),th:nth-child(' + hide + ')').hide();`. If you could be more specific with your question with an example on jsfiddle, it will be a lot easier to help you with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Line 175 and 176 of main.js:

```
$('td:nth-child(' + show + '),th:nth-child(' + show + ')').show();
$('td:nth-child(' + hide + '),th:nth-child(' + hide + ')').hide();
```

It looks like you are trying to swap out a column here, but your selectors aren't quite right. In particular, it looks like when you se the nth-child value to "2", you end up selecting another, larger td element. Which is why, after you call hide(), your layout breaks.

Try changing your selector to better specify what you want to show or hide. For example:

```
$('#advantage-calculator td:nth-child(' + show + ')').show();
$('#advantage-calculator td:nth-child(' + hide + ')').hide();
```

(I'm not sure why you were selecting `th`'s in the first place so I took those out)

Comment: It worked like I wanted it to after I took out out those two lines.
Thank you, Michael!